# how do i divide grid by number of element?

Tags: reactjs

```js
const value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

I want

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7
```

---Row configuration---

```
<Row>
  <Col/>
  <Col/>
  <Col/>
</Row>
```

How can I make it like above?

Also, I hope it will continue to be applied even if the number is added to the list.

Comment: Do you want to pass values into `Col` like this `<Col>1 2 3</Col>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a good ol' `for` loop.

```
function Component() {
  const value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const numPerRow = 3;
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i += numPerRow) {
    const slice = value.slice(i, i + numPerRow);
    rows.push(
      <Row key={i}>
        {slice.map((value) => (
          <Col key={value}>{value}</Col>
        ))}
      </Row>,
    );
  }
  return <>{rows}</>;
}
```

You can of course make this a more functional-y helper:

```
function mapSlices(arr, sliceLength, fn) {
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += sliceLength) {
    output.push(fn(arr.slice(i, i + sliceLength), i));
  }
  return output;
}

function Component() {
  const value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  return (
    <>
      {mapSlices(value, 3, (slice, i) => (
        <Row key={i}>
          {slice.map((value) => (
            <Col key={value}>{value}</Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```